# AngularJS ng-select and ng-switch-when issue

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to add a selection menu to my angular charts and I'm running into some problems. I used [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/tLUETg3FzTqYije5nERf?p=preview) selection app template and tried to incorporate it into my current app. However the only thing that shows up on the page is the selection menu and the axis of the graph.

I looked at the console log for any errors that may have sprung up and found that one of the src url wasn't found, and updated the url in my current code. This did not solve my problem, however, and no more errors showed up in the console to give me some insight as to what I'm doing wrong. This is my second time ever working with the selection directive so its difficult for me to spot any errors in my code.

My markup:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
     <title>Angular Chart</title>
     <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.11/d3.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts/bower/dist/angular-charts.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <select ng-model="selection" ng-options="item for item in items">
       </select>
      <hr/>
      <div ng-switch on="selection">
        <div ng-switch-when="Selection 1">
           <div 
              data-ac-chart="'line'" 
              data-ac-data="data[0]" 
              data-ac-config="config" 
              class="chart">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="Selection 2">
           <div 
              data-ac-chart="'line'" 
              data-ac-data="data[1]" 
              data-ac-config="config" 
              class="chart">
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </body>

 </html>
```

My JS:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularCharts']);
    myApp.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.config = {
        title: 'Products',
        tooltips: true,
        labels: false,
        mouseover: function() {},
        mouseout: function() {},
        click: function() {},
        legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'right'
       }
      };
       $scope.data = [{
         series: ['Sales', 'Income', 'Expense', 'Laptops', 'Keyboards'],
         data: [{
           x: "Laptops",
           y: [100, 500, 0]
          }, {
           x: "Desktops",
           y: [300, 100, 100]
          }, {
           x: "Mobiles",
           y: [351]
          }, {
           x: "Tablets",
           y: [54, 0, 879]
          }]},
          {
         series: ['Sales', 'Income', 'Expense', 'Laptops', 'Keyboards'],
         data: [{
           x: "Laptops",
           y: [10, 500, 0]
          }, {
           x: "Desktops",
           y: [30, 200, 10]
          }, {
           x: "Mobiles",
           y: [357, 127, 20]
          }, {
           x: "Tablets",
           y: [54, 0, 879]
          }]
         }];
       $scope.items = ['Selection 1','Selection 2'];
       $scope.selection = $scope.items[0]
     }
   ]);
```

Edit: I see now that the problem lies in the js file in the data model. I initially thought that it was the data array inside `$scope.data` that was being called in the html tag of the div, so I simply created two different data arrays under that model as `dataA` and `dataB` in place of `data`. However, the series array is also required in the data model for the `data-ac-data` directive to function properly.

I'm confused as to how I should format the code in the model so as to easily call the data in the html when a selection is made. I'm also not sure if I can use an expression such as `"{{data.dataA}}"` in place of `"data"` in the html tag. Please let me know the easiest way to modify my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `$scope.data` model. It needed two groups of elements each with a `series` and `data` array. The directive was also modified to `data-ac-data="data[0]"` and `"data[1]"` respectively.

Comment: Pleased you solved it. If this was the answer, would you click the tick icon to the left? This is how we mark questions as resolved here. Thanks!

Comment: It won't let me accept my own answer as an answer until two days after I've answered my own question.

Comment: No worries @Nick, no rush `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
ac-data="dataA" 
ac-data="dataB"
```

Should be

```
ac-data="data.dataA"
ac-data="data.dataB"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not work. In my edit I mentioned that I found that the problem is with the value I placed in `data-ac-data`. The value `"dataA"` doesn't work because the value for the directive requires there to be a data array (like `dataA` and `dataB`) as well as a `series` array, which is found in `$scope.data`. The question now becomes how do I reformat `$scope.data` so that it contains two elements, each of which have a `series` array and a `data` array that could then be inserted into the directive `data-ac-data`